# C#.net error with return command

Tags: c#, batch-file

i am using c#.net Microsoft Visual Vtudio .NET Framework version  4.5.2

I really did not want to make this question but i have this code that I am doing right now what will edit txt file , then will write the edited txt file to disk and use cmd and command "certutil" to crypt it . 
Then it will add @echo (crypted text what the code edited)>>C:\users\%username%\appdata\file.txt at the front and end of the crypted line in the text file.
Maybe I can edit the resource file directly ? But then the command "certutil" can't access the file because its in .exe . I guess i will need to write the file to disk ,then do the "certutil" and then read the file back to resources maybe ?

I want to make builder for that so I / somebody else  wont need to edit it every time , then crypt and then edit the bat when it echos the crypted text to appdata and runs it .

I am running to some problems because I started to learn c week ago .then i found out that you cant have gui for c and then started to use visual studio to make things .

This is the error :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (radioButton2.Checked) 
            {
                string text = Properties.Resources.bindyes; 
            }
            else if(radioButton1.Checked)
            {
                string text = Properties.Resources.bindno;   
            }
            bool downurl = textBox1;
            var downexe = textBox2;
            var bindurl = textBox4;
            var bindexe = textBox3;
            File.WriteAllText("C:\\Users\\Karl\\Desktop\\downloader.bat",);
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to return this value from code

```
if (radioButton2.Checked) 
{
    string text = Properties.Resources.bindyes;
    return text;
}
else if(radioButton1.Checked)
    string text = Properties.Resources.bindno;
return text;
{
```

but i get this error:

> Error Since 'Form1.button1_Click(object, EventArgs)' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression  .

I really don't want to ask this but I have struggled with this 1 and half day / pretty bad right now.

Is there any fix to this ?

So il try to make it little bit clearer.writing from tablet

I want to make builder what will write a file with user inserted information in the right places of file then use cmd to crypt the file . then read\add this at the front of every line "@echo " and at the end of every line i want to write" >>c:users\%username%\appdata\file.txt

And other part of code like

Certutil decodehex(or decode)c:\filepath\file (the decoded file path)

So i want to make if statemnt so if radiobox1.checked it will set the string for text to 
    If (radiobox1.Checked)
    {
    String text = Properties.Resources.nobind
    Else 
    String text = Properties.resources.yesbind
    Return text;
    }
    I wrote it from head

And then i want to write the file in resources to c:\filepath.
But i cant return :\

I hope that explains little pit better

Comment: It's really not clear what this code is doing (the lack of indentation doesn't help), but the error is pretty clear.  If a method has a `void` return type then you can't return anything from that method.

Comment: Ok. Return those strings to what

Comment: [If a tree falls in a forest and no one is around to hear it, does it make a sound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_a_tree_falls_in_a_forest)... Why would you want to return value from click handler - there is no code expecting the result... Some clarification, and formatting would definitely make your post better (and give chance to someone to answer).

Comment: I suggest you read up on what it means to return a value from a method, and then you'll see that it definitely isn't what you want to do with the value in this case. There is nowhere to return it to. And if you did return from the method then the below code to write the batch file would not be run.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to write the variable `text` to the file, then all you need to do is move the declaration of the variable outside the if-else. Declaring a variable inside a `{`..`}` block means it doesn't exist outside.

```
string text; // declare it here
if (radioButton2.Checked) 
{
    text = Properties.Resources.bindyes; 
}
else if (radioButton1.Checked)
{
    text = Properties.Resources.bindno;   
}

File.WriteAllText("C:\\Users\\Karl\\Desktop\\downloader.bat", text);
```

Answer (score -4):

I don't know C#,but, I think you need to change `private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` to `private string button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`. Since 'void' mean's you are returning nothing. Hope this helped.

Comment: You can't arbitrarily change method signatures without breaking other code. This is one of the ones you can't change at all, other than the name of the method and the names of the arguments, the return types and parameter types/order must be preserved.

Comment: if you not sure your answer is right post as a comment

Comment: Ok so they are Pre defined Methods. Sorry didn't know that as I don't know C#. If the program is for Application development then he could just display the results in a Message Box or text box right?

Comment: Perhaps a dumb question, but if you don't know C#, why did you posted an "answer" on it? **`:/`**

Comment: It's just that I can understand/read C# but I haven't explored it  fully especially aspects of C# related to GUI.At the time when I answered I didn't know that 'button1_Click()' and other similar event/action handler were 'Pre declared' methods.So I thought you could modify the return type and also the signature of the method.